# Connect with Facebook without reloading the page

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-php-sdk

I'm writing a web app that relies on logging in via Facebook. Here's what I want to do:

1. When the user clicks the "Connect with Facebook" button on the web
   app, another tab will open in his browser with the Facebook login
   link that lets him authenticate the app.
2. Once the user authenticates the app, the login tab will close, the
   the user will be on the original web app page
3. The web app will detect that the user has connected with Facebook,
   and logs the user in.

Right now, the only solution I can think of is having the web app continuously querying Facebook to see if the user has been logged in, is there a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 2):

Integrate login with the [Facebook Javascript SDK](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/). (rather then the PHP sdk) You don't need to reload the page. You can deal with logged in user states in the callbacks.

```
//load the async FB sdk
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId      : 'YOUR_APP_ID', // App ID
      channelUrl : '//WWW.YOUR_DOMAIN.COM/channel.html', // Channel File
      status     : true, // check login status
      cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
      xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML
    });

    // Additional initialization code here
  };

  // Load the SDK Asynchronously
  (function(d){
     var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
     if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
     js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
     ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
   }(document));

//Do something when the user is logged in
FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function(response) {
  //do something with response object
});
</script>
```